# The request has exceeded the allowable time limit Tag cfhttp in mailchimp

Tags: api, authentication, coldfusion, mailchimp

I am getting an error saying **"The request has exceeded the allowable time limit Tag: cfhttp".**I have downloaded code form riaforge `http://mailchimp.riaforge.org/`  my code is -
**index.cfm**

```
<cfsetting requesttimeout="600" />
    <cfset application.mc.apiKey = "YourAppkey-us8">
    <cfset application.mc.url = "http://127.0.0.1:8500/mailchimp/MailchimpWrapperV-0.99/">
    <cfset application.mc.output = "xml">
    <cfset url= "http://#listlast(application.mc.apiKey, "-")#.api.mailchimp.com/1.2/">
    <cfset mc = createObject("component","components.mailchimp099").init(application.mc.apiKey,application.mc.url,application.mc.output)>
    <cfset dob = mc.login()>
```

changed login credential in **mailchimo099.cfc**page in login function.

```
<cfhttp url="#getServiceURL()#" method="post">
        <cfhttpparam name="username" value="YouLoginEmailId" type="URL">
        <cfhttpparam name="password" value="YourPasssword" type="URL">
        <cfhttpparam name="output" value="#getOutput()#" type="url">
        <cfhttpparam name="method" value="login" type="URL">
</cfhttp>
```

but it is giving me an error saying "**The request has exceeded the allowable time limit Tag: cfhttp**" in this line `<cfhttpparam name="method" value="login" type="URL">`.
**How to solve this  error?**

**Is there any other simple mailchimp API to use mailchimp features?**

Comment: The "The request has exceeded the allowable time limit" is fairly self explanatory: the call to the URL you're requesting is taking longer than the request timeout you have set. What you should perhaps be asking is why it is a request to `http://127.0.0.1:8500/mailchimp/(etc)` is taking more than the 10min request timeout you are setting (*10min*, really?). Or another question... is the request actually taking more than 10min, or is it timing-out earlier than that?